# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {parameterId, parameterName, parameterValue})

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I get Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {parameterId, parameterName, parameterValue}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. whenever the editData.parameter is not equal to null. How do I fix this? I have tried numerous of bug fixing but it is not accepting my code.

```
<Autocomplete
              options={params}
              getOptionLabel={(option) =>
                `${option.parameterName} - ${option.parameterValue}`
              }
              value={editData.parameters || null}
              onChange={handleAddParamChange}
              isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
                option.parameterId === value.parameterId
              }
              sx={{ width: "88.5%", mb: 2 }}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField {...params} label="Select Parameter" />
              )}
            />
```

It should be accepting the data even when the editData.parameter is not null. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you show some sample data? like params and editData.parameters

Comment: The sample value of editData.parameters is like this

"editData" {
   "parameters": {
                "parameterId": 29,
                "parameterName": "test 1",
                "parameterValue": "sdwsd"
            },
}

the params consist of an array of the parameter objects

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code right now, are you sure the error is not thrown from other code that's using editData?

Comment: Yes. When the editData.parameters is not equal to null it throws this error Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {parameterId, parameterName, parameterValue}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.  But when it is not null there is no error. I am still confuse with this error.

Comment: The autocomplete does accept object as value, the only possible reason that I can think of is other code renders the value directly as a component. Can you try removing all other references from editData and see if the problem still persists?